# Android Stocks (Financial) App w/ Sparklines (Like Apple Stocks)

Tags: android, ios

I'm trying to find an Android app for viewing stock quotes that has sparklines on the main list, like on the iOS stocks app:

[image]

Or like this:

[image]

I would've thought this would be a very basic & common feature, but after trying dozens of apps, I've only dug up one single result: StockSpy. Unfortunately, it  feels pretty dated & clunky, so I was hoping I was missing another.  Considering how common stock investing is, and how common iOS->Android migrations are, surely there must be other similar options I'm somehow failing to turn up?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hey did you end up finding a valid android app with the spark lines?

Comment: Nope, didn't find one & gave up.